# How to use DefinitelyTyped in Angular2 project?

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I'm using [Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) jQuery plugin in my Angular2 project. I found a type definition file for this library at DefinetlyTyped

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/autosize

I'm using a custom directive at the moment and everything seems fine.

**autosize.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import '../../../../../node_modules/autosize/dist/autosize.js';

declare var jQuery: any;
declare var autosize: any;

@Directive ({
    selector: '[Autosize]'
})

export class AutosizeDirective {
    constructor (private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        let initAutosize = jQuery(this.el.nativeElement);

        autosize(initAutosize);
    }
}
```

How can I add the above mentioned type definition file here?

Comment: so you want to use a jquery plugin into angular2 as a directive?

Comment: @Aravind is there any bad effects to use jquery plugins like select2 which if created by ourselves might take lots of time to build a single component. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is your exact requirement

Comment: using select 2 type of select element